# Android: Make a Service check something periodically

Tags: java, android, android-service

I have been researching Services, but I cannot figure out a way to do something periodically. I realize that when a service is called, it calls the OnCreate() method and the onStartMethod() but what I want to do is do a process every 10 minutes or so (subject to change). So in which method/how would I make the service execute code on an interval of a certain time?

I'm sorry if I missed something in the Android documentation.

[EDIT]

More specifically, I want to update some information and see if it is any different than the existing one -- and then issue a taskbar **Notification** to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to check out AlarmManager, it's an easy way to do what you want. It'd also be nicer in terms of memory usage, battery, etc. than keeping a service open for 10 minutes just waiting to do something.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html